# How to customize scheduled events in a calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, calendar, ruby-on-rails-5, schema

I am looking schema for calendar events which includes weekly, monthly and daily events particularly for random days in a week.

In a rails application, I used `simple_calendar` gem to generate monthly, weekly calendar. Is it possible to configure event creation for say Mon, Wed, Fri between 10-11 AM, if so how should I do that using the simple_calendar gem?

Currently my database schema look like the following,
Schema for calender event

```
name  string
description string
start_date datetime
end_date datetime
duration string
is_scheduled boolean 
scheduled_type string (monthly, daily, weekly)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the README:

> Simple Calendar is designed to do one thing really really well: render a calendar.

This is not the right tool to use for creating/tracking/scheduling events.  Maybe take a look at something like [Montrose](https://github.com/rossta/montrose) or [IceCube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube)